# ngx-bootstrap timepicker when only hour is entered with keyboard the value remains undefined

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

When one enters hours only (manually), timepicker seems to not set the value in the model.
When one only changes the hours with the arrow controls the value is set.
Is this a bug? Can I avoid it through configuration ?

P.S. I do not want to set a default value at start, because I have to be able to determine if no value was set as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to another ui library... too many problems with ngx-bootstrap...